# Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, face-recognition

I have been writing a code about autoencoencoder for face recognition the part of code I used is as follows:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
print(face_cascade)
img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/exmpforbike6/training_images/JenniferGroup.jpg')
print(img)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print("voici",gray)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

a = []
for i in range(0, faces.shape[0]):
    a.append(gray[faces[i][1]:faces[i][1] + faces[i][3], faces[i][0]:faces[i][0] + faces[i][2]])
```

this is the error i get :

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

the error is in this line:

```
for i in range(0, faces.shape[0]):
    a.append(gray[faces[i][1]:faces[i][1] + faces[i][3], faces[i][0]:faces[i][0] + faces[i][2]])
```

Any idea on how I can fix it??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python OpenCV face detection code sometimes raises \`'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761340/python-opencv-face-detection-code-sometimes-raises-tuple-object-has-no-attrib)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761340/python-opencv-face-detection-code-sometimes-raises-tuple-object-has-no-attrib) link from 2016.

"The cause of the problem is that [`detectMultiScale`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) returns an empty tuple () when there's no matches, but a numpy.ndarray when there are matches", so the `AttributeError` you're getting makes some sense.

You should add some validation code to catch this case, and check either if `detectMultiScale` has returned results, or what's the data type of your variable before using `.shape[0]`.

Comment: In the future, if a question is a duplicate, please flag it for closure. As an aside, what a crappy API design!

Comment: Sorry, will do next time, I'm still getting the hang of SO. And I agree, the whole Numpy/PyPlot/OpenCV stack can be so easy to get results with, but also so frustrating from time to time.

Comment: No worries, just FYI for next time.

Comment: If that solves your problem, feel free to accept the answer, so it's there for future reference. Have a nice day